# Vaadin Servlet login with salt-hashed password

Tags: java, hash, passwords, vaadin, vaadin7

We use Vaadin (7) and have used the following demo as base for our application:

- Demo: http://demo.vaadin.com/archetype-application/
- Source code: https://github.com/vaadin/archetype-application-example

During development my colleague (who is currently on vacation) also has made some changes regarding the login. In the original Source code above we see the following `login()`-method:

```
private void login() {
  if (accessControl.signIn(username.getValue(), password.getValue())) {
    loginListener.loginSuccessful();
  } else {
    showNotification(new Notification("Login failed", 
      "Please check your username and password and try again.", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE));
    username.focus();
  }
}
```

In our application this has been changed to this:

```
private void login() {
  try {
    VaadinServletService.getCurrentServletRequest().login(
      this.username.getValue(), this.password.getValue());
    this.loginListener.loginSuccessful();
  } catch (...) {
    // Here we do some things on fail, which is irrelevant for this question
  }
}
```

And not sure if it's relevant, but we have this UIServlet:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "OurUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = OurUI.class, productionMode = false)
public static class OurUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5302116211234266347L;
}
```

---

My experience with Vaadin is less than that of my colleague unfortunately, so I have a couple of questions (which I will also ask him when he's back from vacation):

1) First of all I'm a bit confused as to how this Servlet's login method knows where to look for the username and password. In our (Oracle) database we have a table like this:

```
USER:
USR_ID     NUMBER(16, 0)
USR_NAME   VARCHAR2(50 BYTES)
PASSWORD   VARCHAR2(256 BYTES)
... (Full name, email, language, etc.)
```

Where is configured that this Servlet's login knows to look for the `USR_NAME` and `PASSWORD`?

2) I've made a class which uses `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` as hashing method, including the use of a random salt (of course). This class also has a boolean method accepting a string and a saved hash, and checks if it's the correct password.
I can add this class if anyone wants to know it, but its implementation is irrelevant. The only thing you need to know is that it uses a random salt (which means the hash is always random and doesn't exactly match a previous hash), and it has a boolean method to check if a password being hashes and the hash in de database both represent the same password. So I can't simply compare the database-hash with the generated hash, because they are different. I have to use the boolean-method.

So, my main question is where I have to implement this boolean method? Currently the Servlet's login does something as a black box to check if the given username/password matches the one in the database, but how can I replace this so it can login by checking the boolean method with a random salt instead?

Comment: You need to open the black box. Look at `accessControl.signIn(..)` , this is where your credentials get validated. When you see the type of the accessControl object, you should be able to find the directions...

Comment: @AndréSchild When I look in the `HttpServletRequest.login(String, String)` - with Ctrl+T in Eclipse - I only see the following: https://s30.postimg.org/hbgeusn01/Http_Servlet_Request_login.png. So where do I see this `accessControl.signIn(...)` method? I think you're referring to the added Source of the demo I added, but we don't use that login. My colleague has changed this to the Servlet login. All the 'magic' is done by this `HttpServletRequest.login(...)`, I'm just trying to understand what happens under the hood and how it accesses the database's user-data.

Comment: In that case look at your servlet container authentification setup